# Rails.Vim :RInvert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, migration, ruby-on-rails-plugins

How reliable is this plugin for writing down migrations. Some people in the rails community I have spoken with have told me they swear by it and others are telling me to just stay away. Any and all thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is phenomenal, but I have had it not work quite right before. However, I would highly recommend doing a `rake db:migrate:redo` after running a migration for the first time anyways to make sure that the up and the down both work. Even if it only writes 90% of the down migration for you, I don't know why you would stay away.

Answer (score 1):

From Rails 3.1 onwards, for most cases, you don't need to write a *down* method. The migrations will have one *change* method and Rails automatically does the down migration in case of rollbacks.

Refer: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#writing-your-change-method

Answer (score 0):

If you're just generating DDL changes (adding columns, etc), it has always been rock solid for me. However, if you're removing columns or generating DML statements such as copying data from one field to another, translating data, etc... :RInvert will not handle those.  But there's still no reason I can think of to not use what they do generate as a starting point. If you don't like the generated down migration by :RInvert, just delete it and you're no worse off than before you ran it.